# Prestashop two modules use identical name and give "Cannot redeclare class" fatal error

Tags: php, class, prestashop, fatal-error, redeclare

How to avoid "Cannot redeclare class" fatal error when two modules use the same class name in prestashop?

For example, I have module which declares and uses a helper class Foo.
I install a new module which has a different helper class but with the same name Foo. So that causes "Cannot redeclare class" fatal error when I go to modules page. I cannot even uninstall that new module.

Comment: Rename one class or uninstall one module. There is no "NameSpace" concept in PHP, so there is no other way to avoid name-duplication.

Comment: @KarmaEDV No namespace concept? Did you get out of your cave for the past seven years ? Namespaces were introduced in PHP 5.3 in 2009.

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre Indeed, that was about the time where php stopped being relevant (to me anyway). Cool, thanks didn't know that and sorry. Going now back to ignoring php if you don't mind :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you'll have to edit one of those two modules and change its class declaration and every occurrence of that class in its other php files.

In the next version of Prestashop (1.7) the notion of namespaces will be introduced with the use of Symfony 2 Framework.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that namespaces does not work in current 1.6 version and wasted my time to try some.

Answer (score 2):

When creating modules that use custom classes / object models, you need to **namespace** them. In PrestaShop you cannot use PHP's [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) feature (because the PrestaShop core is not adapted to work with it), but you can do it the old way by prefixing your class name. For example:

```
// Your module:
class MyModule extends Module

// Your custom ObjectModel:
class Message extends ObjectModel
```

Class name `Message` is **very** generic and will mostly like come to conflict with some other module that has poorly chosen to name it's classes.

To prevent this, you must prefix your class names:

```
class MM_Message extends ObjectModel
```

In this case `MM_` is short for `MyModule`. This is much less likely to conflict with other modules or classes. Event a better way would be to prefix the whole module name:

```
class MyModule_Message extends ObjectModule
```

Also, name your database table according: `ps_my_module_message`. This also makes easy to navigate the database table. Prefixing class names is very good practice, in fact, I do it all the time. The downside might be longer class names.

**P.S** If you want to uninstall a module that is conflicting, you need to temporarily disable on of them. A good way would to temporarily rename the module folder to something else (folder of the module that you want to leave), then uninstall the other module. After that, restore the original folder name. Renaming module folder will prevent it from loading.
Technically your could try to disable it in back-office, if it's not loaded in BO

Comment: Thank you. All what you suggested is OK and that is what I have been doing. However, There may be a time when someone choose exactly identical name for one of his class and user may be unable to access server to change folder name, etc... you know...
That's why I asked this question to know if there is any better way that I am missing and that can avoid this problem 100%.

Comment: Basically you suggested some techniques but this is not an answer. So is the answer NO, THERE IS NO WAY TO AVOID IT WITH 100% ASSURANCE???

Comment: You cannot avoid something that some other developer **failed** to do. If you are developing a module yourself, then you should follow there recommendations and there will be no problems